# Clue to prove that the third coordinate of two points in a tangent plane differ by 1.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I am trying to solve the following problem: Given a revolution surface S generated by rotating the curve $\alpha(t)=(t,0,ln(t))$ around the Z axis, we consider the point p in S and the tangent plane in p $T_{p}S$. If q is the intersection point of $T_{p}S$ and the Z axis, prove that the third coordinates of p and q differ by 1.

I have calculated a parametrization of S, which is $\vec{x}(u,v)=(vcos(u), vsin(u), ln(v))$, and we can write the equation of the tangent plane using the partials of said parametrization. I have calculated a normal vector (not the unit normal, because I don´t think it needs to be that one) which is $\vec{n}=(cos(u), sin(u), -v)$ and using this vector and $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$, the equation of the tangent plane is:

$$T_{p}S: xcos(u)+ysin(u)-zv+p_{3}v-p_{2}sin(u)-p_{1}cos(u)=0$$

Now, using that $q=(0,0,q_{3})$ is also in $T_{p}S$, I can write the following equation:

$$q_{3}=\frac{-p_{3}v+p_{2}sin(u)+p_{1}cos(u)}{-v}$$

I'm not sure of how can I continue to solve this problem. Is my proccess correct or would there be a better way to solve this? If it is, any clue on how to follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is right, you are just missing some information to finish. Notice that $\vec n(u,v)$ would be the normal vector to the tangent space of $S$ **at the point $p=\vec x(u,v)$,** not at an arbitrary $p$.

Hence you only need to substitute, in the last equation you wrote: $$p_1 = v\cos(u), p_2=v\sin(u), p_3= \ln(v)$$
Substracting now $q_3 - p_3 = q_3 - \ln(v)$ and simplifying gives the desired result.